# Why does +"1" return an int?

Tags: javascript

```
return "1";  // returns string
return +"1"; // returns int
```

I'd like to know what this method is called when using **+"*n*"** to convert from string to int.

Comment: because in this particular case, the `+` is being interpreted as "make this value positive"-type operation. a "negative string" doesn't exist, so the string-1 gets coerced to an int. it'd be no different if you had `return -"1"`, except you'd get a negative back instead

Comment: Tried adding a +"1" comment, [got rejected by the quality filter](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheDevTeamThinksOfEverything).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just the intrinsic type coercion that the unary `+` operator performs according to the language spec.

1. Let *expr* be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
2. Return ToNumber(GetValue(*expr*)).

So although conceptually it's just the opposite of unary `-`, since a `+` operation just means "multiply by positive `1`" the only real work that's done is to coerce the value to a number.

Answer (score 4):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_%28.2B%29):

> ## Unary plus (+)
>
> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its
> operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't
> already. Although unary negation (-) also can convert non-numbers,
> unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something
> into a number, because it does not perform any other operations on the
> number. It can convert string representations of integers and floats,
> as well as the non-string values true, false, and null. Integers in
> both decimal and hexadecimal ("0x"-prefixed) formats are supported.
> Negative numbers are supported (though not for hex). If it cannot
> parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> +3     // 3
> +"3"   // 3
> +true  // 1
> +false // 0
> +null  // 0
> ```

Comment: This is lifted from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators, but with the sentences separated into paragraphs... for some reason.

Comment: Plagiarized from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B) .. copied text should be placed within blockquotes, and you should link to the source

Comment: Don't try to sidestep the issue. You need to cite your sources. That is a rule. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do

Comment: @CatalinMunteanu no that's not the problem I think, juste cite the sources, it gives the impression you try to somehow hide this information, even though it is probably not the case

Answer (score 1):

You are using the unary operator `+` which tries to cast anything to its right to a Number (as a float).

Note that it may return `NaN` if it can't be cast to a Number.

Similarly you can use `parseFloat`, which may return `NaN` as well

```
parseFloat(anyValue, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're applying the unary operator `+`.

It's not defined for string, so JS has to convert the string to a number first.

Of course, be careful not to accidentally turn it into a binary operator. It's not something you want to use in real code, because it's kind of fragile :)